# server crashes after failed axios get request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, socket.io

I created a function to find data by ID from api if there is one and create new one if there isn't.
 But server crashes if the first axios.get() fails with 400 code when data corresponding to the provided ID doesn't exist. 
 Originally had try and catch block around the axios get and post and thought they might be causing the crash but removing them yields same result.

```
async function findOrCreateDocument(id) {
  if (id == null) return;
  let response = await axios.get(api + `/${id}`);

  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) return response.data;

  response = await axios.post(api, { id: id, data: defaultValue });
  document = response.data;

  return document;
}
```

This function is called inside of a socket.io server.

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("join-document", async (documentId) => {
        const document = await findOrCreateDocument(documentId);
        socket.join(documentId);
        socket.emit("load-document", document.data);
        socket.on("send-text-change", (delta) => socket.broadcast.to(documentId).emit("recieve-text-change", delta));
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically when the server "crashes" it prints out some error message ... And `try ... catch` seldomly "cause" crashes, but prevents them (if used correctly)...

Comment: `axios` typically throws an error on an unsucessful request (ie `response.status >= 400`). You are not catching that error anywhere. Thus you have an uncaught exception ... See the [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors) on handling errors

Comment: I wrapped it back with try and catch and added if (response) return response.data; Then it worked like a charm. Seems like trying to access fields from response object caused the crash, not axios.get(). Thanks for the help.